# keep input values on submit with errors and clear them when the submit is successful (php)

Tags: php, validation, input, error-handling, submit

I have a simple form (it´s in a modal and reloads in the same page) which I want to remember the input values if it was filled incorrectly and forget them if it was inserted correctly in the db.
My code remembers the value in both cases and I don't want that.

Thanks for your help.

HTML:

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" i" name="user" value = "<?php echo isset($_POST['user']) ? $_POST['user'] : '';?>/">
  <button type="submit" name="register-btn">Crear cuenta</button>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['register-btn'])){
    include_once('includes/connect_db.php');

    $usern = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['user']);

    if(empty($usern)){
     exit();
       echo "error"
    }
    else{
      $varsql = "INSERT INTO registers (user) VALUES ('$usern');";
    }
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Good to see the query value is escaped, Also important to escape before rendering `htmlentities($_POST['user])`

But to answer your question, You can execute the PHP before the form is rendered, and `$_POST['user] = null` when the process was successful. Three for the post value will be clear before the form is rendered again.